Is the $0$ a semisimple module?
As is widely recognized, the $0$ is not a simple module. Consequently, can the $0$ be considered a semisimple module?
A module over a (not necessarily commutative) ring is said to be semisimple (or completely reducible) if it is the direct sum of simple (irreducible) submodules.
Can we consider $0$ as a semisimple module, since it is the direct sum of zero simple modules?
Is there a general convention that considers $0$ as a semisimple module or one that does not?

Thanks for sharing the information with me.
